# Skype - main.db got broken

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, skype

I was exploring `main.db` file in Skype folder in Roaming folder (`%AppData%`) with [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index). But Skype was on at that time. And somebody texted me and at that point I was reading data from `Messages` table. Then Skype crashed. I terminated Skype and copied Skype folder to desktop (like a backup). Closed SQLiteSpy with ignoring any changes and tried to sign in to my Skype account. But it failed. I deleted the Skype folder from `%AppData%` and now I have empty Skype. Only my contacts are saved, but no chat history. Also SQLiteSpy shows `database disk image is malformed` when I press the `Analyze database` from `Execute` tab.

I don't know what to do. Skype can't read `main.db` file but SQLiteSpy reads it perfectly, I can't read my conversations...

Is it possible to recreate `main.db` file? Can I somehow get chat history back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the database by clicking `Vacuum database` button in SQLiteSpy.